# Is it possible to rename oneself on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Looking around on the site, I found a post with my name I didn't remember having posted.

Although I should have known my first name is not that unique, I never realized there could be 31 of me around here.

Is it possible to add my last name for example? In contrast with my first name, the second one will not have many "duplicates".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, see this image for directions:

[image]

I got there clicking the image of my icon from the top bar.

Comment: perfect! how could I overlook...

Comment: ha! Graag gedaan :+) and I can see you managed :=D (you did check that there are no 2 Jacob Vlijm?)

Comment: I did! Only one, en dat ben ik :)

Comment: Gezellig! Lage landen boven!

Comment: @don.joey I think all Askubuntu members are Dutch, writing English for no reason

Answer (score 6):

With the new design of SE, the previous answer isn't valid anymore, though the steps are almost the same.

1. Click your name at the top
2. Click on "[Edit Profile & Settings](https://askubuntu.com/users/edit/current)"
3. Change your display name and Save.

Note, that you can only change your display on the main site. The setting isn't available if you edit your profile on a meta site.

[image: Ask Ubuntu Profile Settings]