# What is this notification with orange background for?

Tags: support, notifications

I saw this image in [this answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8898/163331), what is the notification with the orange background in the right top corner for?

[image]

Comment: You need 2k rep for me to disclose that information to you :+)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means there is 1 review waiting for me that is related to "suggested edits".

This example shows what is shown when I clicked the orange 1:

[image]

Down the image there is a compare between old and new (not included) with the name of the editor. The buttons to the right let me aprove or reject it or I can improve it or skip it.